# Need help in Apache Camel multicast/parallel/concurrent processing

Tags: apache, apache-camel

I am trying to achieve concurrent/parallel processing in my requirement, but I did not get appropriate help in my multiple attempts in this regard.

I have 5 remote directories ( which may be added or removed) which contains log files, I want to Dow load them for every 15 minutes to my local directory and want to perform Lucene indexing after completion of ftp transfer job, I want to add routers dynamically.

Since all those remote machines are different end points , and different routes. I don't have any particular end point to kickoff all these.

```
Start 
<parallel>
        <download remote dir from: sftp1>
       <download remote dir from: sftp2>
          .... 
</parallel>
<After above task complete>
<start Lucene indexing>
<end>
```

Repeat above for every 15 minutes,

I want to download all folders paralally, Kindly suggest the solution if anybody worked on similar requirement.

I would like to know how to start/initiate these multiple routes (like this multiple remote directories) should be kick started when I don't have a starter end point. I would like to start all ftp operations parallel and on completing those then indexing. Thanks for taking time to reading this post , I really appreciate your help.

I tried like this,

```
from (bean:foo? Method=start).multicast ().to (direct:a).to (direct:b)... 

From (direct:a) .from (sftp:xxx).to (localdir) 
from (direct:b).from (sftp:xxx).to (localdir)
```

Answer (score 0):

- camel-ftp support periodic polling via the consumer.delay property
- add camel-ftp consumer routes dynamically for each server as shown in [this unit test](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/camel-core/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/builder/AddRoutesAtRuntimeTest.java)
- you can then aggregate your results based on a size or timeout value to initiate the Lucene indexing, etc

[todo - put together an example]

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response, I saw the code that you have given for adding routes dynamically, what is my need is 

`
<from uri="seda:start"/>
<multicast>
   <to uri="direct:a"/>
   <to uri="direct:a"/>
<multicast>

when I add <direct:c> like above

<from uri="seda:start"/>
<multicast>
   <to uri="direct:a"/>
   <to uri="direct:a"/>
   <to uri="direct:c"/>
<multicast> 
`

does the above code converts like this?, because I want to add another router which is similar to what I have added as parallel to those already started processes).